# QTP row and column count is always 1

Tags: excel, vbscript, qtp

I am writing a piece of code to copy data from a web table to an excel sheet. I don't understand why I am getting row count and column count 1. Is there something else that I need to add?

Here is my code:

```
Dim XL
Set XL=createobject("Excel.Application")
XL.Workbooks.Open "D:\QTP\RailwaysforSurat.xlsx"
Set nsheet = XL.Sheets.Item(1)
row=Browser("title:=.*").Page("title:=.*").WebTable("html tag:=TABLE", "index:=0").GetROProperty("rows")
msgbox row
cols=Browser("title:=.*").Page("title:=.*").WebTable("html tag:=TABLE", "index:=1").GetROProperty("cols")
msgbox cols
```

This not complete code. I have trouble getting rows and columns count. Please help!

P.S. I am using this website for the testing "http://www.indianrail.gov.in/cgi_bin/inet_trnnum_cgi.cgi"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you are using Descriptive Programming techniques to identify the WebTable, but you're using extremely generic descriptions for everything.  Perhaps that's just scrubbed for the sake of posting publicly,  but the important thing that I notice is that your code to read Rows is trying to find a table with Index of 0 and your code to read Cols is trying to find a table with index of 1...

This means you are accessing two different tables.  Are you sure that your descriptions are finding the table that you think you want?

My suggestion is to:

1) bring up the page in your browser so that you can see the table.
2) Bring up QTP and open the GuiSPY
3) Click the pointing hand over a cube button to begin spying
4) Click on something inside the table you are trying to work with.

GuiSPY will snap back and show a hierarchy of objects that it found.  Next, you want to positively identify what level in that hierarchy is the table at...  I would...

5) starting at the top (Browser), select the top row and click "Highlight in Application" and watch what gets lit up.
6) go down the hierarchy list clicking the next item in the hierarchy and clicking "Highlight in Application" until you see it flash on the exact table you're trying to target.
7) Once you have isolated the table, click the button for "Copy the identification properties to the clipboard" button, then close GuiSPY.
8) Open a notepad, or just use QTP's editor window itself and paste in what GuiSPY copied to clipboard.

Ok, you now have a complete list of everything QTP was able to see about the specific table you want to detect.  From here, you want to look through the list of properties and find one (or two) that would positively identify that table every time.. For example, on this very page, the table that holds your question could be identified as:
WebTable("text:=I am writing a piece of code to copy data")...  (*note I've shaved it down because it's automatically a Regex string...   With some cleanup, it could be:

```
Browser("StackOverFlow.Com").Page("Question 36663629").WebTable("text:=I am writing a piece of code to copy data"))
```

Now replace your .WebTable("html tag:=TABLE", "index:=0") with that data you've selected, and try it again.  Hopefully you can lock in on the exact table you're expecting and get the info you need.

Answer (score 1):

The indianrail page did not open so cannot see the table you are testing. But QTP provides default methods for rows and columns, try using that and see if it works.

```
NumRows = Browser("Mercury Tours").Page("Search      Results").WebTable("OutboundFlights").RowCount

NumColumns = Browser("Mercury Tours").Page("Search Results").WebTable("OutboundFlights").ColumnCount(1)

ColumnCount takes row number as parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what tables you are looking at, but if it is Services and information then the rows/cols value for those table is 1.The whole web page is consisted of concatenated web tables. So its going to be little tricky to capture that information. Try using a child object method and count the number of links within the web table, its going to look something like this -

```
Set oWebEdit=Description.Create
oWebLink("micclass").value="Link"
Set olink = Browser("title:=.*").Page("title:=.*").WebTable("").childobjects(oWebLink)
 olink.count
 msgbox olink.count
```

'Then initiate a for loop

```
For i = 0 to olink.count-1
```

' Get the link name

```
olink. count(i).GetRoproperty("name")
```

'Initiate an array and save the link names

If get link name does not work then you can use childitem method.
Also make sure you are using the correct index for the tables or define some other properties as well.

P.S. If you are going to use DP in future and haven't already then read about Childitems/childobjects methods.They come in real handy while using DP.